# Count words in a string method?

Tags: java, string, methods, count

I was wondering how I would write a method to count the number of words in a java string only by using string methods like charAt, length, or substring.

Loops and if statements are okay!

I really appreciate any help I can get! Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
public static int countWords(String s){

    int wordCount = 0;

    boolean word = false;
    int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // if the char is a letter, word = true.
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i != endOfLine) {
            word = true;
            // if char isn't a letter and there have been letters before,
            // counter goes up.
        } else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && word) {
            wordCount++;
            word = false;
            // last word of String; if it doesn't end with a non letter, it
            // wouldn't count without this.
        } else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

Comment: You need to take into account apostrophes and quotes, and other special characters.

Comment: You use contractions in your comments ("isn't", "doesn't", "wouldn't") but your code cannot handle them. It won't handle crime-fighting canines, either.

Answer (score 84):

This would work even with multiple spaces and leading and/or trailing spaces and blank lines:

```
String trim = s.trim();
if (trim.isEmpty())
    return 0;
return trim.split("\\s+").length; // separate string around spaces
```

More info about split [here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Small correction. The last line should be `return words.length;`

Comment: I would use \\W here instead of \\s, because you could have something other than space separating words.

Comment: Short, sweet, and effective.

Comment: @Trejkaz \\w in code above will return 0 if there is only one word in the string. Which is not correct

Answer (score 16):

Hi I just figured out with StringTokenizer like this:

```
String words = "word word2 word3 word4";
StringTokenizer st = new Tokenizer(words);
st.countTokens();
```

Comment: This works, but it is not a String method, it uses a separate StringTokenizer class. The question is for how to do this without using other classes.

Comment: I like this answer.  The person who asked this question originally was probably getting the answer to some homework assignment anyway.

Come to think of it, your second line needs to be:
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(words);

Answer (score 9):

Simply use ,

```
str.split("\\w+").length ;
```

Comment: I gotta point out that this doesn't work correctly in many cases since it has a number of upvotes.
`" ".split("\\w+").length` yields 1 (empty or blank string). `" a ".split("\\w+").length` yiedls 2 (one word with trailing spaces)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static int countWords(String str){
        if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
            return 0;

        int count = 0;
        for(int e = 0; e < str.length(); e++){
            if(str.charAt(e) != ' '){
                count++;
                while(str.charAt(e) != ' ' && e < str.length()-1){
                    e++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 private static int countWordsInSentence(String input) {
    int wordCount = 0;

    if (input.trim().equals("")) {
        return wordCount;
    }
    else {
        wordCount = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        String str = new String("" + ch);
        if (i+1 != input.length() && str.equals(" ") && !(""+ input.charAt(i+1)).equals(" ")) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }

    return wordCount;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
myString.split("\\s+");
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Simple Solution You can Try this code

```
    String s = "hju   vg    jhdgsf  dh gg    g g  g  ";

    String[] words = s.trim().split("\\s+");

    System.out.println("count is = "+(words.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int countWords(String input) {
        int wordCount = 0;
        boolean isBlankSet = false;
        input = input.trim();

        for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
            if (input.charAt(j) == ' ')
                isBlankSet = true;
            else {
                if (isBlankSet) {
                    wordCount++;
                    isBlankSet = false;
                }
            }

        }

        return wordCount + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Don't just post code-only answers. Add some context.

Answer (score 0):

Algo in O(N)

```
 count : 0;

 if(str[0] == validChar ) :
      count++;
 else :
      for i = 1 ; i < sizeOf(str) ; i++ :

          if(str[i] == validChar AND str[i-1] != validChar)

             count++;

          end if;

      end for;

 end if;

 return count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestStringCount {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count=0;
    boolean word= false;
    String str = "how ma ny wo rds are th ere in th is sente nce";
    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i =0;i<ch.length;i++){
        if(!(ch[i]==' ')){
            for(int j=i;j<ch.length;j++,i++){
                if(!(ch[j]==' ')){
                    word= true;
                    if(j==ch.length-1){
                        count++;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    if(word){
                        count++;
                    }
                    word = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("there are "+(count)+" words");      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import com.google.common.base.Optional;
    import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
    import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;
    import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
    import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;

    String str="Simple Java Word Count count Count Program";
    Iterable<String> words = Splitter.on(" ").trimResults().split(str);


    //google word counter       
    Multiset<String> wordsMultiset = HashMultiset.create();
    for (String string : words) {   
        wordsMultiset.add(string.toLowerCase());
    }

    Set<String> result = wordsMultiset.elementSet();
    for (String string : result) {
        System.out.println(string+" X "+wordsMultiset.count(string));
    }


add at the pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>r09</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting Words in a String:

This might also help -->

```
package data.structure.test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class CountWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// Couting number of words in a string
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter Your String");
        String input = br.readLine(); 

        char[] arr = input.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
    boolean notCounted = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        if (arr[i] != ' ') {
            if (notCounted) {
                notCounted = false;
                counter++;
            }
        } else {
            notCounted = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("words in the string are : " + counter);
}

}
```

Comment: You really need to add some sort of explanation past just the basic code.

Comment: i am not sure what to add. i think the code itself is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File f=new File("src/MyFrame.java");
    String value=null;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
try {
    Scanner  in =new Scanner(f);
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
    String a=in.nextLine();
    k++; 
    char chars[]=a.toCharArray();
    i +=chars.length;
    }
    in.close();
    Scanner in2=new Scanner(f);
    while(in2.hasNext())
            {

        String b=in2.next();
        System.out.println(b);
        j++;
            }
   in2.close();

    System.out.println("the number of chars is :"+i);
    System.out.println("the number of words is :"+j);
    System.out.println("the number of lines is :"+k);





}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My idea of that program is that:

```
package text;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CoutingWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String str;
        int cWords = 1;
        char ch;

        BufferedReader buffor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Enter text: ");
        str = buffor.readLine();

        for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isWhitespace(ch)){ cWords++; }
        }
        System.out.println("There are " + (int)cWords +" words.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to stackoverflow but I hope my code helps:

```
private int numOfWordsInLineCounter(String line){

     int words = 0;

         for(int i = 1 ; i<line.length();i++){
         Character ch  = line.charAt(i-1);
         Character bch = line.charAt(i);
             if(Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) == true && Character.isLetterOrDigit(bch)== false ) words++;
             if(i == line.length()-1 && Character.isLetterOrDigit(bch))words++;
         }
     return words;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A string phrase normaly has words separated by space.  Well you can split the phrase using the spaces as separating characters and count them as follows.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;

public class WordCountMethod {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        Map<String, Integer>m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String phrase = "hello my name is John I repeat John";
        String [] array = phrase.split(" ");

        for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++){
            String word_i = array[i];
            Integer ci = m.get(word_i);
            if(ci == null){
                m.put(word_i, 1);
            }
            else m.put(word_i, ci+1);
        }

        for(String s : m.keySet()){
            System.out.println(s+" repeats "+m.get(s));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the chosen answer as a starting point the following deals with a few English language issues including hyphenated words, apostrophes for possessives and shortenings, numbers and also any characters outside of UTF-16:

```
public static int countWords(final String s) {
    int wordCount = 0;
    boolean word = false;
    final int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // if the char is a letter, word = true.
        if (isWordCharacter(s, i) && i != endOfLine) {
            word = true;
            // if char isn't a letter and there have been letters before,
            // counter goes up.
        } else if (!isWordCharacter(s, i) && word) {
            wordCount++;
            word = false;
            // last word of String; if it doesn't end with a non letter, it
            // wouldn't count without this.
        } else if (isWordCharacter(s, i) && i == endOfLine) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}

private static boolean isWordCharacter(final String s, final int i) {
    final char ch = s.charAt(i);
    return Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)
            || ch == '\''
            || Character.getType(ch) == Character.DASH_PUNCTUATION
            || Character.isSurrogate(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put this together. The incrementer in the wordCount() method is a bit inelegant to me, but it works.

```
import java.util.*;

public class WordCounter {

private String word;
private int numWords;

public int wordCount(String wrd) {
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(wrd, " ");
    word = token.nextToken();
    numWords = token.countTokens();
    numWords++;

    return numWords;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userWord;

    WordCounter wc = new WordCounter();

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence.");
    userWord = input.nextLine();

    wc.wordCount(userWord);

    System.out.println("You sentence was " + wc.numWords + " words long.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create variable count, state. initialize variables
if space is present keep count as it is else increase count.
for eg:

```
if (string.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {
state = 0;
} else if (state == 0) {
state = 1;
count += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

*lambda, in which splitting and storing of the counted words is dispensed with*
*and* only *counting is done*

```
String text = "counting w/o apostrophe's problems or consecutive   spaces";

int count = text.codePoints().boxed().collect(
    Collector.of(
        () -> new int[] {0, 0},
        (a, c) -> {
          if( ".,; \t".indexOf( c ) >= 0 )
            a[1] = 0;
          else if( a[1]++ == 0 ) a[0]++;
        }, (a, b) -> {a[0] += b[0]; return( a );},
        a -> a[0] ) );
```

gets: `7`

works as a status machine that counts the transitions from spacing characters `.,; \t` to words

Answer (score -1):

```
if(str.isEmpty() || str.trim().length() == 0){
   return 0;
}
return (str.trim().split("\\s+").length);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    String a = "Some String";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.isWhitespace(a.charAt(i))) {
            count++; 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count+1);
```

**It will count white spaces. However, If we add 1 in count , we can get exact words.**