# How to count words in a string method?

Tags: java, string, methods, constructor

Im trying to create a project with a scanner to read a text file, separate by the number of lines, and also count the number of words in each line. Here is my code so far:

```
    public void getWordsPerLine(){

      try {
           File file = new File("report.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            int count = 0;


            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                count++;


                if (count <= 9){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Line Number: " + count);
                System.out.println(line);
            }


            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


  }
```

Comment: When counting the number of words in a line, what are you considering to be a delimiter? I.e., are the words separated by blank space, tabs, commas, and/or other characters?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a word is a group of characters delimited by spaces, then inputString.split(" ") will produce an array of 'words', which you can then count. You might want to do some extra checking to make sure multiple space characters in a row which produce empty words dont get counted - or use a proper regular expression in the .split() method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the String class's split() method to split the line on whitespace and grab the number of elements in the returned array(equal to number of words in line).

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you read a new line of the text file, pass it to a method that is going to count the words in that line..

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
String line = scanner.nextLine();
countWords(line);
count++;
```

You may want to take a look at a post already answered asking to do the same thing.. [Count words in a string method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method)