# Counting words in a string using methods

Tags: java, string

I have a project to make a program that takes a string as input and then prints the number of words in the string as output. We are supposed to use 3 methods in this, one to read input, one to print the output, and one to count the words.

I know I am missing something basic but I have spent hours on this and cannot figure out why the program wont run as it should. I need to keep the program pretty simple so I dont want to edit it too much, just find the issue and fix it so it will run correctly.

Example: Enter a string of text: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 9 words

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter text: ");
    String words = wordInput(in);
    int count = wordCount(words);
    System.out.println(words);
    System.out.println(count);
    printLine(count);
}

private static String wordInput(Scanner in)
{
    String words = in.nextLine();
    return words;
}
private static int wordCount(String words)
{
    int length = words.length();
    int ctr = 0;
    int spot = 0;
    int stop = 1;
    char space = ' ';
    char end = '.';
    char com = ',';
    char yes = '!';
    char question = '?';

    while (length > 0 && stop > 0)
    {
        if (words.charAt(spot) == space)
        {
            ctr++;
            spot++;
        }
        else if (words.charAt(spot) == com)
        {
            spot++;
        }
        else if (words.charAt(spot) == yes || words.charAt(spot) == end || words.charAt(spot) == question)
        {
            stop = -1;
        }
        else if (spot > length)
        {
            stop = -1;
        }
        else
            spot++;
    }
    return ctr + 1;
}
private static void printLine(int ctr)
{
    System.out.println(ctr + " words");
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? What output are you getting? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: There seems to be a few things that are questionable, you have a while loop that checks `length` on each iteration, but `length` is never modified in the loop. You are using `stop = -1` to break out of the loop, just use `break`.  You are checking if `spot > length` but that is after you have already indexed `words` by `spot` so will surely cause a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: One way to get this working would be to do it incrementally.  You check for ',' '.' and '!' in the program to split words, but you don't have any of those in your input.  Try to do it with just checking for a space, that's an easier problem, then you can try to improve it once you get it working.

Comment: Can you post what the error is? What needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rewritten `wordCount` that does as you request, minimal changes to the code. However, I am not sure it produces the answers you expect.

```
private static int wordCount(String words)
{
    int length = words.length();
    int ctr = 0;
    int spot = 0;
    char space = ' ';
    char end = '.';
    char com = ',';
    char yes = '!';
    char question = '?';

    while (spot < length)
    {
        if (words.charAt(spot) == space)
        {
            ctr++;
            spot++;
        }
        else if (words.charAt(spot) == com)
        {
            spot++;
        }
        else if (words.charAt(spot) == yes || words.charAt(spot) == end || words.charAt(spot) == question)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
            spot++;
    }
    return ctr + 1;
}
```

However, fundamentally you are trying to count words in a string, and that is a known art. A few options and further reading:

- http://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/find-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-java.html
- [Count words in a string method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method)

Which leads to a simpler result of:

```
private static int wordCount(String words) {
    return words.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going on the assumption that whoever enters the string is not going to make a grammar error, try split the string at all spaces and set it equal to a string[]. Here is an example:

```
    String temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter some text here");
    String[] words = temp.split(" ");
    JOptionPane.showMessage(null, String.format("Words used %d", words.length));
```