# Selenium code to find the word count in a paragraph

Tags: java, selenium

Hi I am trying to get the word count in a paragraph. The following is my code to find the count. Kindly check the code and tell me the mistake.

```
Code
----
package checking;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoteWebDriver driver;

        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/");

        WebElement Para = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='banner-secondary']/p"));
        String ParaCon = Para.getText();

        System.out.println("Paragraph Content : "+ParaCon);

        int ParaConCount = ParaCon.length();
        System.out.println("Paragraph Characters Count : "+ParaConCount);

        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= ParaConCount; i++) {
            if (ParaCon.contains("of")) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Count of Word present : "+count);

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

It should get thecount of thw word whatiam giving

Comment: <edit> Actually you break the moment you find it once, which means you can only find it once (count max = 1). Check out this question to see how you can get the amount of times a substring appears in a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string

Comment: Ok i will check. Thanks Floris Velleman

Comment: try this it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method

Comment: I tried the code u gave but i am facing problem. =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package sample;

import org.apache.commons.exec.util.StringUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class WordSearchCountandposition {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoteWebDriver driver;

        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/");

        WebElement Para = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='banner-secondary']/p"));
        String ParaCon = Para.getText();

        System.out.println("Paragraph Content : "+ParaCon);

        int ParaConCount = ParaCon.length();
        System.out.println("Paragraph Characters Count : "+ParaConCount);

        int count=0;
        int position=0;

        String WordtoSearch = "a";

        String a[] = ParaCon.split(" ");
        int size = a.length-1;
        System.out.println("Paragraph Words Count : "+size);

        for (int i = 0; i <=size; i++) {
            if (WordtoSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(a[i])) {
                count++;
                position = i;
                System.out.println("Position of Matched Words : "+position);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Matched Words Count : "+count);

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an example:

```
ParaCon = "of of of"
```

This will give you:

```
ParaConCount = 8
```

And a for loop that looks like this:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
     if ("of of of".contains("of")) {
         count++; // count is now 1
         break; // We get out of the loop here (so we have count = 1)
     }
}
// count is now 1
```

---

What about using:

```
StringUtils.countMatches(ParaCon, "of"); // this will return 3
```

Comment: Hi Floris iam getting problem while adding the .countmatches can u please give the exact coding

Comment: @Vijay The `.countMatches` function requires using Apache Commons Lang. If you do not have access to that you can use `ParaCon.split("of", -1).length - 1`.

Comment: its not working i tried its saying invalid assign operator

Comment: @Vijay Please clarify what you have done, it works when I test it: https://ideone.com/5idZ1W.