# Exercise about reading sentences in Java

Tags: java, string, netbeans, data-structures

I'm trying to read a sentence in Java and to know how many words are in there. This is what I've done:

```
public class TestWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Give your phrase");
        Scanner extr=new Scanner(System.in);

        String Phrase;
        Phrase = extr.nextLine();
        int TotalSizeOfPhrase = Phrase.length();

        double number;
        for (int i=0; i < TotalSizeOfPhrase; i++)
        {
            if (Phrase[i] != number &&  Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)))                    
            {
                TotalWords = TotalWords + 1;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'd like to know how to code this:

```
if (Phrase[i]!= 'of an **arbitrary** number && white space')
```

then:

```
TotalWords = TotalWords + 1;
```

Because it marks a mistake when I type this:

```
Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))
```

Comment: use `Phrase.chatAt`  although you can split `Phrase` on space and just check the value against number and increment your tot

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I actually type Phase.charAt instead of s, but the mistake was still there

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I edited my question

Comment: `Phrase[i] != number` also requires to use with `charAt` , `Phrase` is String not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes

```
    System.out.println("Give your phrase : ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Phrase;
    Phrase = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter age : ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    // replace the number with empty string mean nothing
    Phrase = Phrase.replace(String.valueOf(number), "");
    Phrase = Phrase.concat(" "); // add space at end for loop calculation 
    int TotalSizeOfPhrase = 0;   // set tot =0
    int count=0; // a count variable to keep track of the word length
    for (int i=0; i<Phrase.length(); i++)
    {
        count++;
        if(Character.isWhitespace(Phrase.charAt(i)))
        {
            if(count-1>1){ // if size of word ( -1 is there for space size) 
                           // is greater than 1 than increment count
                TotalSizeOfPhrase=TotalSizeOfPhrase+1;                          
            }
            count=0;            
        }
    }
    System.out.println(TotalSizeOfPhrase);
    scan.close();// don't forget
```

Inuput :

```
Hello i'm 20 and I'm a beginner
20
```

output :

```
5
```

Comment: hmm well I shouldn't assign a number in the code, like 9, I should read it using Scanner (I can do that :),  why the output is 6? It should be 0 because there are not words, just numbers

Comment: so you want to count occurrence of particular number ?

Comment: add some demo test cases in your post with expected input and output

Comment: for example if I give this sentence:" Hello i'm 20 and I'm a beginner", then the program should have as output 5, because there are only 5 words

Comment: a number or a letter doesn't count as a word

Comment: seems like you have some edge cases here , ok , letme update it

Comment: in this `Hello i'm 20 and I'm a beginner` the arbitrary number is 20 ? which should not be included in the final result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151163/discussion-between-pavneet-singh-and-annelise-t).

Answer (score 1):

The way i would do it, is to split the line by white spaces (getting the words), adding them to array and then getting this array length which would be equal to word count.

```
Phrase = Phrase.trim(); //make sure there is no spaces at start or end of the line
String[] words = Phrase.split(" "); //get the words 
int word_count = words.length;  //get the word count in line
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the number of words in the sentence , you could use this code :

```
int numberOfWords = Phrase.trim().isEmpty() ? 0 : trim.split("\\s+").length;
```

Comment: but I haven't saw those ways of code in my class, so I don't think  I'm able to use it

Comment: then checkout the first answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Give your phrase");
    Scanner extr = new Scanner(System.in);

    String Phrase;

    Phrase = extr.nextLine();

    String[] words = Phrase.trim().split(" ");

    System.out.println("Totals Number Of Words: " + words.length);

    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word.trim());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is 23 a word? nop it's a number

Comment: wait I have a better one, type in your code 0 0  0 0 0 , you'll get 5 words as output

Comment: but I have to say, the code looks good and simple :) and I understand it well

Comment: this is relative to how you define a 'word'. actually a number is a word by definition. if you open any word processor program or notepad++ and type 0 0 0 0 0 and then use the count function you will get 5. so your question should be "the count of white-space separated character sequences having length > 1 and excluding numbers and including one arbitrary number"

Comment: write as input this: // 0 //, you'll get 3 words

Comment: I won't bother again:) hehe I was just testing the code