# count words of sentences?

Tags: java, arrays, java-6

i want to  count number of words per sentences i write code but count character for each word in sentences this my code

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type some words, then press enter: ");
    String sentences= sca.nextLine();
    String []count_words= sentences.split(" ");
    for(String count : count_words){
    System.out.println("number of word is "+count.length());}
}
```

Comment: Count the number of spaces " " + 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864184/3010171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String[] count_words= sentences.split(" ");` is splitting the input argument by `" "` that means that length of this array is the number of words. simply print the length out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sca = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type some words, then press enter: ");
    String sentences= sca.nextLine();
    String[] count_words= sentences.split(" ");
    System.out.println("number of word is "+ count_words.length);
}
```

example:

```
oliverkoo@olivers-MacBook-Pro ~/Desktop/untitled folder $ java Main
Please type some words, then press enter: 
my name is oliver
number of word is 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The method call `count.length()` is returning the length of each word because the loop is assigning each word to variable `count`. (This variable name is very confusing.)

If you want the number of words in the sentence, you need the size of the `count_words` array, which is `count_words.length`.