# How to count words (including spaces)?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MyFirstProject {

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {

    //This line will create a buffered reader that reads from the system input using an input stream reader
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //input will contain the first line of input from the user   
    /**
     * This asks a question.
     */
    System.out.println("What is your input?");
    String input = bufferedReader.readLine();
    /**
     * This returns a valediction or the input.
     */
    if (input.equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println("GOODBYE!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(input);
    }


    }


/**
 * This counts the number of words (including spaces) in a string.
 * @param words The user input.
 * @return The number of words in a string.
 */
public static String numberOfWords(String words) {
  int count = 0;
  if (words.length() == 1) {
      count++;
      return (String.valueOf(count) + "word");
  }
  if (words.length() > 1) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= words.length(); i++) {
          if (words.charAt(i) == ' ') {
              count++;
          }
      }
      return (String.valueOf(count) + "words");
  }
  else {
      return (String.valueOf(count) + "words");
  }
}
}
```

My question is pretty simple. I'm struggling to understand why my code won't return the number of words in an input. The output should be like this, if for example the input on console from user is "hello world":

What is your input?
Hello World
Hello World
3 words
1 space
11 characters

Comment: You never call your `numberOfWords` function in your main method.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to java. I don't understand what you mean exactly. Are you saying that it's not within the brackets of the main method? @OHGODSPIDERS

Comment: As @OHGODSPIDERS mentions, you need to call the function on the read input like `String result = numberOfWords(input);`.

Comment: How is the input "Hello World" **three words**?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call your `numberOfWords` function in your main method.

Try this:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MyFirstProject {

  public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {

    //This line will create a buffered reader that reads from the system input using an input stream reader
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //input will contain the first line of input from the user   
    /**
     * This asks a question.
     */
    System.out.println("What is your input?");
    String input = bufferedReader.readLine();
    /**
     * This returns a valediction or the input.
     */
    if (input.equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println("GOODBYE!");
    }
    else {
        //****** HERE'S IS CHANGE! ********
        System.out.println(numberOfWords(input));
    }


    }


/**
 * This counts the number of words (including spaces) in a string.
 * @param words The user input.
 * @return The number of words in a string.
 */
public static String numberOfWords(String words) {
  int count = 0;
  if (words.length() == 1) {
      count++;
      return (String.valueOf(count) + "word");
  }
  if (words.length() > 1) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= words.length(); i++) {
          if (words.charAt(i) == ' ') {
              count++;
          }
      }
      return (String.valueOf(count) + "words");
  }
  else {
      return (String.valueOf(count) + "words");
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight the change? Will be easier to spot then, especially for a beginner.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see! Thank you! I didn't get the output I need but I think I can work with this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zabuza its in the else statement of  main

Answer (score 0):

First, to be able to get the result of computation of function `numberOfWords` you need to call it ith your input, see in code

Next prefer `Scanner` than `BufferedReader + InputStreamReader`, syntax is easier

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is your input?");
    String input = sc.nextLine();                   // change to Scanner

    if (input.equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println("GOODBYE!");
    } else {
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println(numberOfWords(input));  // add method call
    }
}
```

I also give an easier way to achieve your stuff :

```
public static String numberOfWords(String words) {
    int nbWord = words.split("\\s").length;
    int nbSpaces = nbWord - 1;
    return (nbWord + nbSpaces) + " words\n" + nbSpaces + " spaces\n" + words.length() + " characters";
}
```

`words.split("\\s")` splits over spaces and creates an array of the words, its length is the number of spaces

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use split function

```
            String input = "Hello World";
    String w[]=input.split(" ");
    int words=w.length;
    int l=input.length();
    System.out.println("characters "+l);
    System.out.println("words "+words);
    System.out.println("spaces "+(words-1));
```

output: characters 11
words 2
spaces 1

Comment: this not include white space in the length

Comment: it includes space that's why answer is 11

Answer (score 0):

Using **split** and assign the result to an array will make you able to get all the information you need , as you can see i do **trim** first because we are assuming the white space its only between words .

```
words = words.trim();
      String tokens[] = words.split(" ");
```

Below a working example with this method :

```
 words = words.trim();
      String tokens[] = words.split(" ");
      int chars =0;
      int wordsN =0;
      int whitespace = 0;
      for(String s : tokens){
          chars+=s.length();
          wordsN++;       
      }
      whitespace = wordsN-1;
      chars += whitespace;

      System.out.println(chars);
      System.out.println(wordsN);
      System.out.println(whitespace);
```