# convert a string to a list of object using Java 8

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8, java-stream

I have a string

```
"Red apple, blue banana, orange".
```

How could I split it by ", " first then add "_" between two words (such as Red_apple but not orange) and capitalize all letters. I read a few posts and found a solution but it only has the split part and how could I also add "_" and capitalize all letters? :

```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(", ");
   List<Fruit> f = pattern.splitAsStream(fruitString)
  .map(Fruit::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Fruit is a enum object. So basically if I am able to convert a string to a certain format and I am able get a Enum object based on a Enum name.

Comment: another solution `Arrays.asList(str.split(",")).stream()
                 .map(s->s.replace(' ', '_')).map(String::toUpperCase)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map(...)` method to perform transformations on the original `String`. Instead of calling `Fruit::valueOf` through a method reference, split each string on space inside `map(...)`, and construct a combined string when you get exactly two parts:

```
List<Fruit> f = pattern.splitAsStream("Red apple, blue banana, orange")
.map(s -> {
    String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    String tmp = parts.length == 2
    ? parts[0]+"_"+parts[1]
    : s;
    return Fruit.valueOf(tmp.toUpperCase());
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/LvOoXT)

If you need to perform any additional transformations of the result, you can do them in the same lambda code block prior to the `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually need the output to be a list of Fruit and capitalize all letters including orange.

Comment: Why not a simple `String tmp = s.replace(' ', '_');` instead of this baroque `String[] parts = s.split(" "); String tmp = parts.length == 2? parts[0]+"_"+parts[1]: s;`?

Answer (score 2):

Your Enum

```
static enum Fruit {
    RED_APPLE, BLUE_BANANA, ORANGE
}
```

Main code:

```
public static void main(String[] ar) throws Exception {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(", ");
    List<Fruit> f = pattern.splitAsStream("Red apple, blue banana, orange")
            .map(YourClass::mapToFruit)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

Helper method to offload dirty mapping part

```
private static Fruit mapToFruit(String input) {
    String[] words = input.split("\\s");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (words.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
            sb.append(words[i].toUpperCase());
            sb.append("_");
        }
        sb.append(words[words.length - 1].toUpperCase());
    } else {
        sb.append(words[0].toUpperCase());
    }
    return Fruit.valueOf(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: It’s astonishing, how many users have forgotten, how to do a simple “replace one character with another” operation… If `replace(' ', '_')` is too simple (the OP did not indicate that handling arbitrary white-space is necessary), you can use `replaceAll("\\s", "_")`…

Answer (score 2):

Here is another sample:

```
f = pattern.splitAsStream(fruitString) 
        .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.joining("_"))) 
        .map(Fruit::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
StreamEx.split(fruitString, ", ")
        .map(s -> StreamEx.split(s, " ").map(String::toUpperCase).joining("_"))
        .map(Fruit::valueOf).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString = "Red apple, blue banana, orange";
stringArray = yourString.split(", ");
List<string> result;
//stringArray will contain 3 strings
//Red apple
//blue banana
//orange
for(string s : stringArray) {
    //Replace all spaces with underscores
    result.add(s.replace(" ", "_").toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: I’m glad that at least one user remembers `.replace(" ", "_")`. However, your code completely misses the point, as reassembling the array to a single string is not what the OP wants. Further, `for(string s in stringArray)` is not valid Java code…

Answer (score 0):

To split the string you can do:

```
string[] output = fruitString.split(",");
```

You would then have to go through the string letter by letter to find spaces and replace them with strings:`

```
for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < output[i].length(); j++){
       char c = output[i].charAt(j);
       //check for space and replace with _
   }
}
```

then using the .toUpperCase() to conver the first char to a upper letter

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below Code, I have followed the below Steps :

1) Split the String by , first.

2) Again split the result of 1) String by " ".

3) Then if the word counts are more than 1 then only proceed to append the underscore.

Demo:
http://rextester.com/NNDF87070

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
       public static int WordCount(String s){

        int wordCount = 0;

        boolean word = false;
        int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            // if the char is a letter, word = true.
            if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i != endOfLine) {
                word = true;
                // if char isn't a letter and there have been letters before,
                // counter goes up.
            } else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && word) {
                wordCount++;
                word = false;
                // last word of String; if it doesn't end with a non letter, it
                // wouldn't count without this.
            } else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
        return wordCount;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         String cord = "Red apple , blue banana, orange";
        String[] parts = cord.split(",");
        String[] result1 = new String[parts.length];
        for(int i=0; i<parts.length;i++) {

            String[] part2 = parts[i].split(" ");

            if(parts[i].length() > 1 && WordCount(parts[i]) > 1)
            {
                String result = "_";
                String uscore = "_";
                for(int z =0; z < part2.length; z++)
                {
                    if(part2.length > 1 ) {
                        if (z + 1 < part2.length) {
                            result = part2[z] + uscore + part2[z + 1];
                        }
                    }
                }

                result1[i] = result.toUpperCase();
            }
            else
            {
                result1[i] = parts[i];
            }

        }

         for(int j =0 ; j <parts.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(result1[j]);
        }

    }
}
```

References for the WordCount Method:  [Count words in a string method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method)