# Split text from string java

Tags: java, android, text, split

I am having a long text which i want to split in to small sentences.The following is my text.

I tried [Count words in a string method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method) but there the solution given was to split the string             `return trim.split("\\s+").length;`. In my text i don't have any spaces.

> సోషలిజం,అనే,మాటను,గబ్బు,పట్టించడమే,కాంగ్రెసు,వారి,వ్యూహమనీ,అంతవరకూ,ప్రజలలో,సోషలిజం,యెడవున్న,అభిమానాన్ని,ఎక్స్‌ప్లాయిట్,చెయ్యడం,దాని,ఎత్తుగడ,అనీ,అంటే,ఓ,మాటు,నా,మీద,పడిపోయావు,గుర్తుందా.

I know split() is used to split the string. But i don't know how to split above text as there is no space or any other regular expression to split with.

The following code works for splitting the text

```
String string = "1234,56,789,10,1111111,1111112,12";
char[] ch = string.toCharArray();  
int comma_limit = 3;
int comma_count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) 
if (ch[i] == ',') {
    comma_count = comma_count + 1;

if (comma_count % comma_limit == 0)
{
ch[i] = '.';
System.out.println(ch);

     }
  }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what "small sentences" means? Also I have noticed that the text is comma separated. So why not use comma for the split condition?

Comment: Small sentences means i want to split the above sentence into 2-3 sentences.

Comment: How do you define sentences if *there is no space or any other regular expression to split with*?

Comment: To be honest I do not know what language the sample text is thus I do not know how a sentence can end in that language. What I mean is for example in English language a normal sentence can end in a punctuation marks (period, question mark, etc). Maybe you can use that idea to split your text

Comment: is there anyway we can take word count and split the text accordingly?

Comment: I see there is comma, do you want to use comma as a delimiter or want to do a fixed split based on length.

Comment: @Mark The above text is telugu text. I am trying to synthesize the above text. As its too large the synthesizer crashes. That's why now i am trying to split the text into 2 or 3.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi How we can use comma as a delimiter and what is fixed split based on length? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: You can always make use of the ```text``` length and divide it by 2 or 3, then use ```substring``` method to split it based on the number you used to divide. Or as what my first comment suggests you can split it by comma. But that would result to many parts and you said that you'll just need 2 or 3 split parts

Comment: @Mark Can you please give me example for how to use "text length and divide it by 2 or 3, then use substring method to split it based on the number you used to divide"

Comment: You can either call string.split(",") which will return an array of words. Then you can put a fixed number of words together to form sentences. Fixed length option just requires you to use substring. In this case some words also may be split.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi Sorry to ask you as it might be silly to ask. But still i am asking you, can you please suggest me an example?

Comment: Please look at javadoc for String and you will get an answer, unless you are expecting others to solve your homework.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi Sorry for the that. I will look through javadoc. Thanks for your help.

Comment: write your expected  output

Comment: pls look at the below answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this once you will get 3 Strings inside loop, You can increase split count..**

```
    public void splitStr(){
        String str = "";
        String[] split_str = str.split(",");

        int len = split_str.length;

        int split_len = len/3;

        for (int i = 0; i< len; i++){
            String f1 ="";
            if(i == split_len){
                // first string 
                f1 = split_str[i];

                // You will get 3   f1 strings
                split_len += split_len+ i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @satyan_android i will try and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Use split method with comma separator it will return array of separated strings then by using length method, get its size

```
System.out.println(yourString.split(",").length);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, please explain *why* it answers the question.

Comment: here spaces are not there in between two words so we need to use split("$character") otherwise directly we could use the split method

Answer (score 1):

```
static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
}
```

You need to check for corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the split use the "," to split based on the comma character. `return trim.split(",").length;`

Comment: Also based on what are you trying to create the small sentences?

Comment: The text is too large to synthesize and the synthesizer crashes. That's why now i am trying to split the text into 2 or 3

Comment: In the split use an addition parameter to limit the number of split, .split(",", n);  n is an example it is used for splitting n times. If the text is too large then divide the whole thing into two or three parts using the substring method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split it into specific parts use this.

```
String text = "SAMPLEs"; // <- this will contain the large text
int numberOfParts = 2; // the number of split parts

int partLength = text.length() / numberOfParts;

ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {
    int start = partLength * i;
    int end = start + partLength;
    parts.add(text.substring(start, end));
    if (text.length() - end < partLength) {
        parts.add(text.substring(end, text.length()));
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("PART " + i + " contains : " + parts.get(i));
}
```

Result:

```
PART 0 contains : SAM
PART 1 contains : PLE
PART 2 contains : s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split using the comma character

```
String text = "సోషలిజం,అనే,మాటను,గబ్బు,పట్టించడమే,కాంగ్రెసు,వారి,వ్యూహమనీ,అంతవరకూ,ప్రజలలో,సోషలిజం,యెడవున్న,అభిమానాన్ని,ఎక్స్\u200Cప్లాయిట్,చెయ్యడం,దాని,ఎత్తుగడ,అనీ,అంటే,ఓ,మాటు,నా,మీద,పడిపోయావు,గుర్తుందా.";
String[] lines = text.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("SENTANCE  " + i + "  : "+ lines[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String Builder instead of string

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("సోషలిజం,అనే,మాటను,గబ్బు,పట్టించడమే,కాంగ్రెసు,వారి,వ్యూహమనీ,అంతవరకూ,ప్రజలలో,సోషలిజం,యెడవున్న,అభిమానాన్ని,ఎక్స్‌ప్లాయిట్,చెయ్యడం,దాని,ఎత్తుగడ,అనీ,అంటే,ఓ,మాటు,నా,మీద,పడిపోయావు,గుర్తుందా");

int totalString = sb.toString().splitby(",").lenght();
```

Comment: Try StringBuilder because it can store more data than string

Answer (score 0):

Here is substring example you have asked.

```
String longText = "సోషలిజం,అనే,మాటను,గబ్బు,పట్టించడమే,కాంగ్రెసు,వారి,వ్యూహమనీ,అంతవరకూ,ప్రజలలో,సోషలిజం,యెడవున్న,అభిమానాన్ని,ఎక్స్\u200Cప్లాయిట్,చెయ్యడం,దాని,ఎత్తుగడ,అనీ,అంటే,ఓ,మాటు,నా,మీద,పడిపోయావు,గుర్తుందా.";
int longTextLength = longText.length();
int partLength  = (int) longTextLength / 3;
String part1 = longText.substring(0, partLength);
String part2 = longText.substring(partLength, 2*(partLength));
String part3 = longText.substring(2*(partLength), longTextLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by what you are asking. Assuming that you are looking to implement some sort of word wrapping, you can do as follows. It may not be the *Best* way to do it, but it is a way to do it.

```
divideString("This is my sentence! I would like to split this into 3 Strings with about the same length.", 3);

public static void divideString(String raw, int numberOfDivides) {
    int charsPerString = raw.length()/numberOfDivides;
    String[] refined = new String[charsPerString];
    for(int i=1; i < (raw.length()/charsPerString)+1; i++) {
        refined[i] = raw.substring((charsPerString*i)-charsPerString, charsPerString*i);
        System.out.println(refined[i]);
    }
}
```

Which would output the following:

```
This is my sentence! I would l
ike to split this into 3 Strin
gs with about the same length.
```