# Searching for characters in a set of strings

Tags: java, string

I made this program where you can input a string and it will record it and display back to the user the amount of characters in that string and the number of strings entered. For example, if the user types in "Sally" into the text box and clicks the button, it will say the

Number of string: 1

Number of characters: 5

And the user can input more strings if they want, like "Alex" and that will change the number from 1 string to 2 and the number of characters to 9

Anyway I want to make it so there is a second text box where the user can type in a few characters and search for those characters to see how many strings entered previously by the user contains the characters searched by the user

Here is an example of what it should do:
So if the user inputs: "Sally", 'Jack", and "Dachshunds" the program should read back saying that there are 3 strings and 20 characters.

Now if the user types "ac" into the search box, the program will say "The number of strings with 'ac' is 2 
(Strings Jack and Dachshunds contain 'ac')

Here is my code for the entire program if what I said above was confusing

I just need help on how to code the part for searching for specific characters in those strings

I know there is something called get.contains() but I tried to implement it and I was having trouble with it

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class good{
StringSet sSet;
JTextField inputStr;
JLabel numStr;
JLabel numChar;
JTextField inputStr2;
JLabel numofStr;

good() {

sSet=new StringSet();

JFrame f= new JFrame("StringSetYetAgain");
JLabel en=new JLabel("Enter a String:");
en.setBounds(50, 10, 100, 100);

numStr=new JLabel("Number of Strings: 0");
numStr.setBounds(50, 160, 400, 100);

numChar=new JLabel("Number of Characters: 0");
numChar.setBounds(50, 180, 400, 100);

inputStr=new JTextField();
inputStr.setBounds(50, 80, 400, 50);

JButton pushMe=new JButton("Push to include String");
pushMe.setBounds(50, 140, 400, 50);

JLabel enter=new JLabel("String to search for:");
enter.setBounds(50, 230, 400, 100);

inputStr2=new JTextField();
inputStr2.setBounds(50, 300, 400, 50);

JButton pushMe2=new JButton("Search");
pushMe2.setBounds(50, 360, 400, 50);

numofStr=new JLabel("Number of strings with: 0");
numofStr.setBounds(50, 405, 400, 50);


pushMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String s=inputStr.getText();
    sSet.add(s);

    String ns=numStr.getText();
    ns=ns.substring(0, ns.length() - 1)+sSet.size();
    numStr.setText(ns);

    String nc=numChar.getText();
    nc=nc.substring(0, nc.length() - 1)+sSet.numChars();
    numChar.setText(nc);
    inputStr.setText("");
}
});

//I would add the code for the search part here

f.add(en);
f.add(inputStr);
f.add(pushMe);
f.add(numStr);
f.add(numChar);
f.add(enter);
f.add(inputStr2);
f.add(pushMe2);
f.add(numofStr);
f.setSize(550,600);
f.setLayout(null);
f.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new good();

    }

}
```

Here is the source code for the StringSet class

```
public class StringSet {

private String[] arr;
private int count;

public StringSet() {
    arr = new String[200];
    count = 0;
}

void add(String newStr){
    arr[count++] = newStr;
}

int size(){
    return count;
}

int numChars(){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        total += arr[i].length();
    }
    return total;
}

int countStrings(int len){
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        if(arr[i].length() == len)
            ++total;
    }
    return total;
    }

}
```

Here is the part so far for the searching of the characters

```
pushMe2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    public int countOf(String substring, StringSet sSet) {
        int counter = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < sSet.size(); i++)
           if (sSet.get(i).contains(substring))
               counter++;

      return counter;

    }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count words in a string method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864159/count-words-in-a-string-method)

Comment: I would also recommend using this commonly used library in Java: [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add that where you said

> I would add the code for the search part here

```
buttonThatShouldCount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int counter = 0;
        String substring = inputStr2.getText();

        for (int i = 0; i < sSet.size(); i++)
            if (sSet.get(i).contains(substring))
                counter++;

        inputStr2.setText("The substring \"" + substring "\" occurs " + count + " times.");
    }
}
```

You'll also need to add the following method to your `StringSet` class:

```
public String get(int index) {
    return arr[index];
}
```

We need to do this, because otherwise there is no way to access the strings stored in the set.

Comment: Okay, I get what you did but im having trouble putting something like that in my code. I keep getting errors when trying to run it. I did change the substring to `inputStr2` which is what the label for the TextField

Comment: Call this method with the text of your search box and the set that contains all entered strings.

Comment: I added the entire program just to show you what I've done so far

Comment: Would I still use the addActionListener for pushMe2 which is the second button or would I get rid of that?

Comment: That is up to your design. If you want that to happen when the button is pressed, yes, still use the `ActionListener`.

Comment: It says I cant interate over an array. So it says I cant use a for loops which is really confusing in the action listerner

Comment: Wait, is `StringSet` a custom class of yours? Because if it is, change the type of `sSet` to `HashSet<String>`.

Comment: Yeah, I made that a while back and it is supposed to be used for this program

Comment: I've edited my answer, take a look. If that does not work, I need to see the source code for `StringSet`.

Comment: Yeah it doesnt seem to work. I think its an issue with the `ActionListener` and the `ActionEvent` that I put around it

Comment: I put the source code for the StringSet class above

Comment: Oh okay. I added that into the StringSet but i'm still having trouble with the loop that you have above. I try to implement it with the `ActionListener` but I still get issues. Ill show what I mean above. Im going to update it and show what I have so far

Comment: Its at the bottom of the question. Im just not sure what Im doing wrong in terms of formatting the code properly. I was going to change the counter so it would by the numofStr which would change the 0

Comment: You weren't supposed to put the WHOLE method in there haha. ;D Only leave the code inside the method and put THAT into your `ActionListener` in there you can do whatever you want with `counter`.

Comment: Oh lol, but what do you mean by leaving the code inside the method and put that into the `ActionListener`? I dont understand

Comment: I've edited my answer one last time now. The logic is completly finished now and you only *might* need to make some tiny adjustements to your logic.